# How to find norm $||U_n||$ of Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind?

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, orthogonal-polynomials, chebyshev-polynomials

how to find norm $||U_n||$ and the values $U_n(\pm)$ of the Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind?

Comment: Which norm are you talking about?

Comment: in the $L^{\infty}$ norm

Comment: Then it is just [this question](/questions/2665518), no?